# Using windows server 2016 essentials without licence

Tags: windows-server-2016, licensing

I have uninstalled the product key from windows server 2016 essentials using `cscript.exe c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs -upk` from a evaluation copy.

I was just wondering if I can use the server without a license without limitations.

Thanks in advanced.

Cheers,

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it would be technically possible you would be breaking the terms of Microsoft’s license agreements, which probably is not a smart thing to do.

If you want to use a server operating system for free, use a free server operating system.

Examples:

- [Debian](https://www.debian.org)
- [Ubuntu Server](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server)
- [CentOS](https://www.centos.org)
- [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org)

Comment: Ok. But legalities aside. It would be possible?

Comment: I frankly have no idea: I only use Windows professionally since many years, and avoid doing stuff that could put my company in a bad position. That said, it would be very strange if Microsoft didn’t have smarter ways than this to protect their income.